# Unable to use Datetime data in SVM model

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, svm

I have a `dataframe` to predict the energy consumption. The columns. are `Timestamp` and `Daily KWH system`.

When used in the SVM model, I'm getting `Value error` as below:
`ValueError: Unknown label type: array([   0.        ,  127.2264855 ,   80.74373643, ...,    7.67569729,
          3.32998307,    2.08538807])`

Dataset consists of energy consumption for every half hour from Sept to Dec.
Here's a sample dataset

```
           Timestamp                 Daily_KWH_System
0        2016-09-07  19:47:07        148.978580
1        2016-09-07  19:47:07        104.084760
2        2016-09-07  19:47:07        111.850947
3        2016-09-07  19:47:07          8.421390
4        2016-12-15  02:48:07         13.778317
5        2016-12-15  02:48:07          0.637790
```

So far I have done :

Read the CSV

```
 data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/anagha/Documents/Python Scripts/Half_Ho.csv')
```

Indexing

```
 data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'])
 data.index = data['Timestamp']
 del data['Timestamp']
 data
```

Plot the graph

```
 data.resample('D', how='mean').plot()
```

Splitting into Train and Test

```
 from sklearn.utils import shuffle

 test  = shuffle(test)
 train = shuffle(train)

 trainData  = train.drop('Daily_KWH_System' , axis=1).values
 trainLabel = train.Daily_KWH_System.values

 testData  = test.drop('Daily_KWH_System' , axis=1).values
 testLabel = test.Daily_KWH_System.values
```

SVM Model

```
  from sklearn import svm
  model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', gamma=1) 
  model.fit(trainData,trainLabel)
  model.score(trainData,trainLabel)
```

Predict Output

```
   predicted= model.predict(testData)
   print(predicted)
```

Comment: I think you need to decompose your datetimes into individual date-elements such as. month, weekday, hour, etc

Comment: Then it wont be a time series problem right? Any other way?

Comment: It would be. Maybe have a read through this: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/winners-mini-datahack-time-series-approach-codes-solutions/ . It is a time series competition where date time decomposition did very well with XGBoost instead of SVMs. I however use this method everyday with SVR on all types of energy data and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

`SVC` is Support Vector Classification. Using it will treat your labels categorically. It looks like you're actually trying to do regression. (Note your error, "unknown label type"). A good first step would be to check out `SVR`. Or you could bin your values to classes, e.g. 0-10, 10-20, etc.:

[sklearn SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVR.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVR)

Comment: Anyother Algorithm i can use to predict and detect the anomolies

Comment: You would need an unsupervised learning algorithm to do this without labels, if you are not binning them as suggested.

Comment: @Anagha there are many approaches to anomaly detection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection the simplest for you may be sklearn's one class SVM. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Comment: @josh OP has targets (see in their code, `trainLabel`), which could be used as regression targets

Comment: @eqzx Completely agree with you on using SVR. OP does say that they wish to detect anomalies with SVC. In this case you would have to define an anomaly using anomaly labels. If you dont have these then you need some unsupervised like the one you posted.

Comment: @josh got it, i misinterpreted who 'you' was :)